# Condition in populate() is not working

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I want to query Image table with specified user but my code is not working.

```
Image.find().populate('user', { id : '1' }).sort({ updatedAt: 'desc' }).exec(function(err, images){
  console.log(images)
});
```

It still showed with all users.

How to query it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The **populate** method is used to fetch the related data of your model

you should modify your query like following

```
Image.find({ user: '1' }).populate('user').sort({ updatedAt: 'desc' }).exec(function(err, images){
  console.log(images)
});
```

Comment: How about if I want to find by user status like this,
Image.find().populate('user', { status : 'ban' }).sort({ updatedAt: 'desc' }).exec(function(err, images){
  console.log(images)
});

Comment: you have to limit your query by using find({ userId : '1'}) or .where({ user: '1'})

Comment: I mean If I want to find by user.status = 'ban' ,

You solution didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

@Ryan show me that I can do like this,

```
Image.find({ user: '1' }).populate('user').sort({ updatedAt: 'desc' }).exec(function(err, images){
  console.log(images)
});
```

Thanks a lot it's working.

But How about I want to query by user status like this ?

```
Image.find().populate('user', { status : 'ban' }).sort({ updatedAt: 'desc' }).exec(function(err, images){
  console.log(images)
});
```

It's not working. It showed me with all user.

How should I do ?